# How to fix overflow after cast to double precision?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query

```
COS(RADIANS(cast(nullif(dblat, '') as double precision)))
```

and I got the following error:

```
Overflow, 4.818114344e-315 (Double valid range 2.225074e-308 to 1.797693e+308)

Detail: 
-----------------------------------------------
error:  Overflow, 4.818114344e-315 (Double valid range 2.225074e-308 to 1.797693e+308)
code:      1207
context:   Value: '4.818114344e-315', Character: '4'
query:     9094308
location:  :0
process:   query1_66 [pid=0]
```

Please, help me to fix this problem

Comment: Your value is too small to be represented by a `double`, and is basically 0. Since `cos(0)=1` anyway, you should be able to catch this with a `min` or special case...

Comment: These ranges are platform dependent. *The `double precision` type typically has a range of around 1E-307 to 1E+308 with a precision of at least 15 digits.* On windows f.ex. I could run `select cast('4.818114344e-315' as double precision)`. If you want to avoid such errors, you should store your data in `double precision` in the first place. -- You can cast your value to `numeric` first to determine it is greater/lesser then expected:

Comment: f.ex. `select case when n < '2.225074e-308' then 0.0 else cast(n as double precision) end from cast(nullif('4.818114344e-315', '') as numeric) n`

Comment: @Wolfie Can you explain please how to do this?

Comment: Test if the value exceeds the maximum / minimum representable values, don't do your cast if it does! Have a go and post a new question / add to this question with a specific difficulty you are having trying to do it.